# Question about Windows Events

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, events, system

I was talking with an employee the other day and I remember them mentioning a tool that we use that enables you to see what messages the OS sends/receives when an event occurs (for example, when a link is clicked in Internet Explorer (or another browser)).

Can somebody please tell me what this app is called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called Spy++, and it's included with Visual Studio and the Windows SDK.

Comment: Thank you very much, SLaks. I tried to up-vote you but I don't have enough reputation - yet.

Comment: Don't worry. I hit the limit already, so the upvote wouldn't have done me any good.

Comment: Not sure about that. +1 again :)

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed use Spy++ like [@SLaks suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230641/question-about-windows-events/2230659#2230659), but if it's specifically to spy on winforms apps (like your tags suggest), I'd recommend [Managed Spy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163617.aspx). Also from Microsoft *and* with source code.